# Page flickering in SSR for anonymous

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, spartacus-storefront

While running the Spartacus-based Angular application in SSR mode, you can easily observe a flickering effect when loading any page for anonymous.

For instance, the most easily visible example is a Login page, you can try to debug an application with imitation of slow internet and will be able to see, how the view reloads 2 times. It looks like you first get a static view and then, once all JS bundles are loaded, your app is reloaded again by activating a dynamic view, where you can interact.

It may be a problem for mobile users with a slow internet connection since they can see a Login page very fast and even start filling the form, but once JS bundles are loaded, the form will be reloaded respectively and all filled data will be erased.

Is it somehow possible to improve such behavior?

P.S. Enabling `TransferSate` doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: What data dependencies does the login page have? I.e. what data is being fetched asynchronously for the login page?

Comment: Paul, this is a specific behavior of the additional library https://github.com/SAP/spartacus that we use for our SAP CC application. Once the app is rendered Spartacus calls for page data again, to make sure that we show customers valid content.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with Spartacus. You mention `TransferState`, have you tried adding `TransferHttpCacheModule` to your imports in `app.module.ts` specifically? That module enables TransferState globally for all HTTP requests without requiring you to write any TransferState code.

Comment: In our case setting the `initialNavigation` to `enabledBlocking` in the `app-routing.module.ts` helped.
btw: what version of Spartacus you're using?
Also, please note that in our case the improvement was visible only on production build testing.

Comment: Mirosław, we use Spartacus 5.0. `initialNavigation` is already set for our application as well, but we still can see flickering.

Comment: Hard to say without debugging then. However there is one more common cause of flickering, introduced with angular 12, which has `inlinceCriticalCss` set to true by default; Spartacus issue related to it is described here: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/13512

Comment: Mirosław, this is our application https://shop.kloeckner.de/v2/login, on the Login page you will be able to reproduce the issue. It looks like the issue is connected to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13446, since the same behavior is easily reproducible in Spartacus raw application.